# Signature png not displaying

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image

I am trying to create a signature system. It should get data from a forum database and display it in an image. My current implementation is only displaying this:

[image: Current result]

It should display `cover.png`

```
<?php

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/SSI.php')) {
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/SSI.php');
}
else die("GRESKA: SSI.php nije pronaden!");


error_reporting(E_ALL);
$username="root"; // KORSINICKO IME
$password=""; // ŠIFRA
$database="smf"; // BAZA
$host="localhost"; // HOST

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("smf") or die( "GRESKA: Dogodila se greska pri povezivanju na bazu podataka!");

if(isset($_GET['id'])) $korisnikov_id = $_GET['id']; // DOBAVLJA KORISNIKOV ID
else if(isset($_POST['id'])) $korisnikov_id = $_POST['id'];

$korisnikov_id = mysql_real_escape_string($korisnikov_id); 

if(isset($_GET['stil'])) $stil = $_GET['stil']; // DOBAVLJA STIL POTPISA
else if(isset($_POST['stil'])) $stil = $_POST['stil'];

$stil = mysql_real_escape_string($stil); 

if($stil == 1 ) // STIL I
{ 

$query = "SELECT * FROM `smf_members` WHERE `id_member` = '$korisnikov_id' LIMIT 1"; // VADI PODATKE IZ KOJE TABELE?

$rezultat = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($rezultat) == "0") die("GRESKA: Taj korisnicki ID ne postoji u bazi."); // ID JE 0 ILI JOS NIJE REGISTROVAN???

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rezultat);

$ime = $row['real_name']; // KORISNIKOVO TRENUTNO IME
$postovi = $row['posts']; // POSTOVI
$grupe = $row['id_group']; // GRUPA  
$spol = $row['gender']; // SPOL
$email = $row['email_address']; // KORISNIKOV EMAIL
$vreme = $row['total_time_logged_in']; // VREME PROVEDENO NA FORUMU

    // KONVERTER VREMENA
    function secondsToWords($vreme)
    {
        $days=(int)($vreme/86400);
        $hours = (int)(($vreme-($days*86400))/3600);
        $mins = (int)(($vreme-$days*86400-$hours*3600)/60);
        return sprintf("%dd %dh %dm", $days, $hours, $mins);
    }

if($spol == 1) $spoltext = "Musko";
if($spol == 2) $spoltext = "Zensko";
if($spol == 0) $spoltext = "Nepoznato";

// DOBAVLJAMO STVARI DIREKTNO SA PROFILA

global $context, $settings, $modSettings, $db_prefix, $boardurl;

 loadMemberData(array($korisnikov_id), false, 'profile');
 loadMemberContext($korisnikov_id);

  $context['status'] = $memberContext[$korisnikov_id]['online']['text']; // ONLINE/OFFLINE STATUS
  $context['avatar'] = $memberContext[$korisnikov_id]['avatar']['href']; // AVATAR

header("Content-type: image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png"); // PRETVARA STRANICU U SLIKU

$Potpisi = @imagecreatefrompng('cover.png'); // LOKACIJA SLIKE

$BOJA_BELA = imagecolorallocate($Potpisi, 255, 255, 255);

$FONT = "./Fontovi/BebasNeue.otf"; // FONT

$ADMINISTRATOR = 'Administrator'; // RANKOVI
$CLAN = 'Clan';

if($grupe == 1) // GRUPE
{
    imagettftext($Potpisi, 21, 0, 115, 50, $BOJA_BELA, $FONT, $ime); // VELIKO IME
    imagettftext($Potpisi, 17, 0, 115, 90, $BOJA_BELA, $FONT, $ADMINISTRATOR); // ADMINISTRATOR
}
else
{
    imagettftext($Potpisi, 21, 0, 115, 50, $BOJA_BELA, $FONT, $ime); // VELIKO IME
    imagettftext($Potpisi, 17, 0, 115, 90, $BOJA_BELA, $FONT, $CLAN); // CLAN
}

imagettftext($Potpisi, 13, 0, 45, 187, $BOJA_BELA, $FONT, $postovi); // POSTOVI
imagettftext($Potpisi, 13, 0, 174, 187, $BOJA_BELA, $FONT, secondsToWords($vreme)); // VREME PROVEDENO ONLINE
imagettftext($Potpisi, 13, 0, 333, 143, $BOJA_BELA, $FONT, $spoltext); // SPOL
imagettftext($Potpisi, 17, 0, 115, 70, $BOJA_BELA, $FONT, $email); // EMAIL
imagettftext($Potpisi, 17, 0, 115, 110, $BOJA_BELA, $FONT, $context['status']); // ONLINE/OFFLINE INDIKATOR

// DOBAVLJAČ AVATARA SA PROFILA KORISNIKA TE KONVERTER SLIKE
if (exif_imagetype($context['avatar']) == IMAGETYPE_GIF)
$traziavatar = imagecreatefromgif($context['avatar']);

if (exif_imagetype($context['avatar']) == IMAGETYPE_PNG)
    $traziavatar = imagecreatefrompng($context['avatar']);

if (exif_imagetype($context['avatar']) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG)
    $traziavatar = imagecreatefromjpeg($context['avatar']);

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($context['avatar']); // KONVERTOVANJE AVATARA

$context['avatar'] = imagecreatetruecolor(512, 512);
imagecopyresampled($Potpisi, $traziavatar, 16.5, 25, 0, 0, 92, 92, $width, $height);  // PRIKAZ AVATARA

imagepng($Potpisi);
imagedestroy($Potpisi);

}
else if($stil == 2) // STIL II
{  
    // STIL II NASTAVLJATE SAMI
}else { die("GRESKA: Taj stil ne postoji u bazi podataka! Pronadjeni stilovi (1) , (2)"); }

?>
```

Comment: no errors in your logs?

Comment: No, everything should work fine but its not displaying

Comment: Please post your phpinfo. Do you have GD and imagemagick installed? Also you have `$Potpisi = @imagecreatefrompng('cover.png');`... do you have `cover.png` on the same path as your php script?

Comment: Also try the code from here: http://www.hotscripts.com/blog/images-with-php-and-gd/ Is it working?

Comment: Well i do not have gd and imagemagick installed, i do have cover.png, this is phpinfo : http://pastebin.com/hph3EAXT

Comment: that explains it. You need at least GD for it to work with any of the image php functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Comment: try to run your script on a cheap vps and it should work. If not, see if this helps: https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=136656

Comment: Oh sorry but i do have GD just printed out print_r(gd_info()); to see if i have it and its enabled Array ( [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible) [FreeType Support] => 1 [FreeType Linkage] => with freetype [T1Lib Support] => [GIF Read Support] => 1 [GIF Create Support] => 1 [JPEG Support] => 1 [PNG Support] => 1 [WBMP Support] => 1 [XPM Support] => 1 [XBM Support] => 1 [WebP Support] => 1 [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => )

Comment: How come it doesn't show on phpinfo ? Is the pastebin complete? Perhaps it's available but not enabled?  http://mydoubts.in/blog/how-to-disableenable-gd-library-on-xampp/

Comment: its like this in php.ini http://pastebin.com/ACrTZZRR

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

OK, so I went through your code and your image is being saved by `imagecopyresampled` to `$Potpisi` which is your `cover.png` (therefore your base image file is being overwritten).

Change the final part of your code to this:

```
$context['avatar'] = imagecreatetruecolor(512, 512);
imagecopyresampled($context['avatar'], $traziavatar, 16.5, 25, 0, 0, 92, 92, $width, $height);  // PRIKAZ AVATARA

imagepng($context['avatar']);
imagedestroy($context['avatar']);
```

And don't forget to change your content type to png:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
```

Comment: Well even with one content type its not working. I did this by tutorial, but i don't know what is the problem

Comment: Added some test code to check if php can generate the images.

Comment: Lol, something weird just happend, ok, the script should generate for each  user image, and when i tried to upload a cover.png the image that should be just background for text i got to this http://i.imgur.com/dhhEzG8.jpg i dont know why but it's saving cover.png in directory with all data there is, but it should only use cover for text and not actually save it

Comment: I don't understand... Is it that instead of printing the image... it's modifying the cover.png image? And is that cover.png image showing what you want (except that it should be printed in the browser)?

Comment: OK, this time my solution should work. See my edited answer and please mark as solved if it indeed, solves your problem.

Comment: Idk what happend i got it working last night, and then i restarted pc and again not working, code: http://pastebin.com/KYvjCtiS

Comment: Your code looks like the original. You have to edit according to my answer.

Comment: Could this be an issue ? I've tried editing it like you said to but still not working http://pastebin.com/rkqCZ1as

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/k8bRkeex If this doesn't work, I cannot help you anymore, sorry. Try it on a proper vps instead of localhost.

Comment: Nope, the code is ok, but something is not working on localhost